# How to pass a regular expression as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

Why this returns false instead of true.

```
function doit(expression) {

    var regex = new RegExp(expression, 'g');

    alert(regex.test('mename@memail.com'));
}

doit("/^\w+([-+.\']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/");
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAV8Q/

Comment: It doesn't work because `new RegExp` doesn't expect strings bookended with slashes; the first and last characters are part of the literal regex pattern.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Either format your expression properly:

```
function doit(expression) {
    var regex = new RegExp(expression, 'g');
    alert(regex.test('mename@memail.com'));
}

doit("^\\w+([-+.\\']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*");
// no / here, escape \
```

or pass the expression directly:

```
function doit(expression) {
    alert(expression.test('mename@memail.com'));
}

doit(/^\w+([-+.\']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/g);
```

​

---

The slashes (`/`) are not part of the expression, they denote a *regex literal*. If you use a string containing the expression, you have to omit them and escape every backslash since the backslash is the escape character in strings as well.

Comment: Because backslash is an escape character in strings, you need to escape all the backslashes, e.g., `\\w` instead of `\w`.  You'd have much cleaner code if you just supplied an actual RegExp object instead of a string, as in the second option in this answer.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: When you have backslashes in a string you have to escape them: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hAV8Q/4/

Comment: Right, I forgot about escaping the backslash... that's why I avoid using regex as strings ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because when creating a regex with `new RegExp()`, you don't use the delimiters. Remove the `/` from before and after the string.

Alternatively, pass the regex itself by removing the quotes before and after, and leave out the `new RegExp()` call.