# How to pass string as regular expression pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

Same question has been asked here: [How to pass a regular expression as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143702/how-to-pass-a-regular-expression-as-a-function-parameter), and I tried it like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             function validate(value, regexp){
                   //escape special characters
                   var regexp = regexp.replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\\])/g, '\\$1').replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08');
                  return new RegExp(regexp,'g').test(value);
             }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
           var regexp = "^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
           alert(validate("alex@domain.com",regexp))
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work,and I am sure the string of pattern is right,and I have tested it in firebug like this:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test("test@domain.com")
```

It matches email correctly.so Please tell what mistakes I have made,thanks.

Comment: Why are you escaping all the special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` one more time while giving it inside the delimiter `"`

```
var regexp = "^(([^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
```

OR

```
var regexp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Comment: Can I take the "var regexp = regexp.replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\\])/g, '\\$1').replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08');" as escaping?