# How to pass a RegEx expression as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, regex

What is the easiest way to construct a java regular expression and pass it to a method that expects a String? Ideally something similar to [SO JavaScript solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143702/how-to-pass-a-regular-expression-as-a-function-parameter).

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty(/* Regex here*/));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to construct a java regular expression and pass it to a method that expects a String?

You can't. You can only use regular expressions with methods that are written to accept them, you can't use them with any method that just accepts a string (such as [`System.getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)).

Methods accepting regular expressions, either explicitly as `Pattern` instances or implicitly as strings (like [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)), will say clearly that they do in their JavaDoc.

Comment: So the solution to the above would be to fetch all with `System.getProperties()`, save to a List or a map, loop through it and match?

Comment: @Andrey: Specifically for system properties, yes.